# Local Notification Triggers when uninstalled and reinstalled the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

when i set an local notification for an upcoming time and when deleted the app, the local notification triggers while i re installed the app. Is there any method to avoid this. Why this happens??

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in applicationDidFinishLaunching (not tested):

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

BOOL firstRun = [prefs boolForKey:@"firstRun"];

if(firstRun) {

    // Cancel all UILocalNotifications

} else {

    BOOL firstRun = NO;
    [prefs setBool:firstRun forKey:@"firstRun"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there was a callback when your app was deleted you could `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` however as this is not possible I don't see any way...

Answer (score 1):

You should implement like below code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, Hope this can be working.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   // BOOL firstRun=YES;

      BOOL firstRun = [prefs boolForKey:@"firstRun"];

    if(firstRun) {
                  NSArray *notificationarray  = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

         BOOL firstRun =NO;
         [prefs setBool:firstRun forKey:@"firstRun"];

     } else {  
               BOOL firstRun = NO;
              [prefs setBool:firstRun forKey:@"firstRun"];
               NSArray *notificationarray  = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
              NSLog(@"%@",notificationarray);

      } 

     [prefs  synchronize];
```

Hope this helps